# How do I define the density of system?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, density, volume, molecular-dynamics

Lets' say I have a solid system made with *N* atoms in a box with a volume of *V* as shown below. In this case, the number density of my system is simply $\frac{N}{Volume\; of \; occupied\;3D\; space}$.

[image: Solid Sphere]

but what if I have a system with $N$ atoms in the same box, but $N_{1}$ atoms are in the solid phase and $N_{2}$ atoms are in the gas phase $\left( N_{1} + N_{2} = N \right)$.

[image]

How should I calculate the number density in this case? Do I consider the whole box volume $V$?

Comment: This seems to be a question of what definition *you* choose for number density.

Comment: You come up with a criteria to distinguish solid from vapor, which is a pretty standard thing in MD. Matter Modeling SE might be a better place to ask since they have experience over there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you take the whole volume. That is the definition of density $\rho = N/V$. I guess what you are thinking of is in fact local density $\rho(r) = \delta N(r) / \delta V$ where $\delta N(r)$ is the number of particles in the immediate vicinity $(x\pm 0.5dx, y\pm 0.5dy, z\pm 0.5dz)$ of the point $\vec{r} = (x,y,z)$, $\delta V = dx\, dy\, dz$.